# Android - Listener value from Fragment to Adapter?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Im working on an app which has a RecyclerView inside a Fragment. My objective, is to set up onClickItemListener trough the adapter.

However, i encountered a problem setting it up: when i call the adapter, i have to put two parameters, which are the list that i need to apply, and the listener.

If i put `this` as listener, i get a TypeMismatch error.

**What can i use instead of `this`?**

**Fragment.kt**

```
class FragmentItems : Fragment() {
    var itemList = mutableListOf<DataItems>()

    ....

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        ....

        rvTracks.apply {
            setHasFixedSize(true)
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
            
            //Cant use 'this'!
            adapter = AdapterList(itemList, this)
        }
    }
}
```

**Adapter.kt**

```
class AdapterList(
    var listItems: List<DataItems>,
    var listener: OnItemClickListener
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterOneColumn.ItemsViewHolder>() {

    inner class ItemsViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView), View.OnClickListener {
        init {
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this)
        }

        override fun onClick(p0: View?) {
            val position : Int = adapterPosition
            if(position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                listener.OnItemClick(position)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ItemsViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_1_column, parent, false)
        return ItemsViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return listItems.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ItemsViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.itemView.apply {
            itemOneColumnTitle.text = listItems[position].stringTitle
            itemOneColumnDescription.text = listItems[position].stringDescription
        }
    }

    interface OnItemClickListener {
        fun OnItemClick(position: Int)
    }
}
```

Comment: if `FragmentItems` is implementing `OnItemClickListener`, you should be able to pass a reference to  `FragmentItems`, otherwise whatever is implementing that interface is what you have to pass there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to make this work

```
adapter = AdapterList(itemList, this)
```

Your class should realize `OnItemClickListener` that you want to pass, you can fix it by :

```
class FragmentItems : Fragment(), OnItemClickListener { ...
```

Comment: Trying your solution seems almost correct... i still get a type mismatch using "this"

Comment: you should realize the corrent `OnItemClickListener` in your fragment, i think in your example it should be `View.OnItemClickListener`

Comment: No, it should be `class FragmentItems : Fragment(), AdapterList.OnItemClickListener`

Comment: Yes it is AdapterList.OnItemClickListener. Although even adding that, and the required function OnItemClick, the adapter still asks for a listener. Putting "this", gives yet again type mismatch

Comment: Have you overridden  `fun OnItemClick(position: Int)` in the `Fragment` that implements `AdapterList.OnItemClickListener`, @Meltix?

Comment: @Onik yes, automatically added by Android Studio, still getting issues with the listener, yet again, TypeMismatch

Comment: @Meltix, besides in the `rvTracks.apply { }` block `this` refers to `rvTracks`, which I believe is _RecyclerView_, not `FragmentItems`. You should use `adapter = AdapterList(itemList, this@FragmentItems)` instead.

Comment: @Onik And of course the easiest solution always works.